# Ising 2D Optimization

Tags: performance, algorithm, math, simulation, c99

I have implemented a  MC-Simulation of the 2D Ising model in C99.
Compiling with gcc 4.8.2 on Scientific Linux 6.5.
When I scale up the grid the simulation time increases, as expected. 
The implementation simply uses the Metropolis–Hastings algorithm.
I tried to find out a way to speed up the algorithm, but I haven't any good idea ?
Are there some tricks to do so ?

Comment: You should first understand where your program is slow. This is called profiling. 
You should also measure how the simulation time varies with size.

Comment: @jimifiki you should add the part about profiling to your answer, it's important.

Answer (score 3):

As jimifiki wrote, try to do a profiling session.
In order to improve on the algorithmic side only, you could try the following:

- **Lookup Table:**
  When calculating the energy difference for the Metropolis criteria you need to evaluate the exponential exp[-K / T * dE ] where K is your scaling constant (in units of Boltzmann's constant) and dE the energy-difference between the original state and the one after a spin-flip.
  *Calculating exponentials is expensive*
  So you simply build a table beforehand where to look up the possible values for the dE. There will be (four choose one plus four choose two plus four choose three plus four choose four) possible combinations for a nearest-neightbour interaction, exploit the problem's symmetry and you get five values fordE: 8, 4, 0, -4, -8. Instead of using the exp-function, use the precalculated table.
- **Parallelization:**
  As mentioned before, it is possible to parallelize the algorithm. To preserve the physical correctness, you have to use a so-called checkerboard concept. Consider the two-dimensional grid as a checkerboard and compute only the white cells parallel at once, then the black ones. That should be clear, considering the nearest-neightbour interaction which introduces dependencies of the values.
- **Use GPGPU:**
  You can also implement the simulation on a GPGPU, e.g. using CUDA, if you're already working on C99.

Some tips:
- Don't forget to align C99-structs properly.
- Use linear Arrays, not that nested ones. Aligned memory is normally faster to access, if done properly.
- Try to let the compiler do loop-unrolling, etc. (gcc special options, not default on O2)

*Some more information:*
If you look for an efficient method to calculate the critical point of the system, the method of choice would be finite-size scaling where you simulate at different system-sizes and different temperature, then calculate a value which is system-size independet at the critical point, therefore an intersection point of the corresponding curves (please see the theory to get a detailed explaination)

I hope I was helpful.
Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that your simulation times scale at least with the square of the size. Isn't it?

Here some subjestions:

If you are concerned with thermalization issues, try to use parallel tempering. It can be of help.

The Metropolis-Hastings algorithm can be made parallel. You could try to do it.

Check you are not pessimizing the code.

Are your spin arrays of ints? You could put many spins on the same int. It's a lot of work.

Moreover, remember what Donald taught us:

```
premature optimisation is the root of all evil
```

Before optimising you should first understand where your program is slow. This is called profiling.